# Javascript global objects stops working after prototype change!

Tags: javascript, oop, firefox4

I don't if I am missing something obvious, but when I do something like below:-

```
Object.prototype.inherit = function(fromClass) {
  fromClass.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

  for(var key in fromClass.prototype){
    if(typeof fromClass.prototype[key] == 'function')
        this.prototype[key] = fromClass.prototype[key];
  }
};
```

Then I can no longer work with any objects. I always get undefined. Similary when I try to 'inject' some method into `Array.prototype` then arrays stop working! I am using Firefox 4.0.1.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PLEASE, *PLEASE*, **PLEASE**, ***PLEASE*** DO NOT EXTEND OBJECT.PROTOTYPE.

Thank you.

Now getting on to your question, what do you mean you can no longer work with objects?  You're going to break for-in loops, but short of that everything should still work.

Comment: Can you please explain, what I broke? And what about extending Array? It also doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post a code sample?  You break for-in loops by extending `Object.prototype`, e.g. `for(var n in obj){ ... }`

Comment: Hey @cwolves thanks for big word of caution. I didn't know that doing this was dangarous, now after Googling I could find what I needed to know. It seems extending `prototype` puts the [new method accessible via for-each](http://erik.eae.net/archives/2005/06/06/22.13.54/). I now remeber Arrays was not `undefined` but had my defined method in it, so breaking my code. In this case I am not sure why I get `this` as null. Anyway I will go ahead create a standalone method instead. Thanks.